# About short attributive clauses in English

Tags: adjective-phrases, attributives

> I have a problem that is hard to solve/ code that is not working anymore.

vs.

> I have a hard-to-solve problem/ not-working-anymore code. (hard-to-solve/ not-working-anymore are not really words in the dictionary)

There are so many cases we use an attributive clause to modify a noun, but it's just too short that I feel it's kind of trouble to add the formal subject and the be verb.

Do native-speakers feel the same?

In Mandarin we use the second way of expressing, But how do English-speaking people express such things?

Is there a third way to express this?

Answer (score 1):

In your examples

> I have a **hard-to-solve** problem.

is perfectly good and many native speakers use it.

However,

> **not-working-anymore code**

is not used, one would simply say

> My code is not working anymore.
>   My code stopped working.
>   My code is having problems.

If you did use your expression, most people might think you were making a joke

> My **not-working-anymore** code has gone on vacation.